# G Data Studio - purpose of forFilterOnly?

Tags: looker-studio

I made a community connector and my endpoint is getting hits like:

```
   "fields":[ 
      { 
         "name":"field1",
         "forFilterOnly":true
      },
      { 
         "name":"field2"
      }
   ]
```

Now, the documentation (https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference) says:

> forFilterOnly - Marks a field only used for filtering the request. It
>   should not be returned in the getData() response.

But then the same field is listed in dimensionsFilters:

```
   "dimensionsFilters":[ 
      [ 
         { 
            "fieldName":"value1",
            "values":[ 
               "dummy value"
            ],
            "type":"INCLUDE",
            "operator":"CONTAINS"
         }
      ],
      [ 
         { 
            "fieldName":"field2",
            "values":[ 
               "some value 2"
            ],
            "type":"INCLUDE",
            "operator":"EQUALS"
         }
      ]

    ]
```

If it's really not needed, why include its filtering options in dimensionsFilters?!

Should I skip all fields that have forFilterOnly=true?

Answer (score 1):

`forFilterOnly` on a field means that the field isn't actually going to be shown in a table/vizualization, but is needed in order for a filter to be applied. This property was introduced when we enabled community connectors to apply [filters](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/filters) (instead of Data Studio).

For your specific question, you should either:

1. Return data for all fields (including `forFilterOnly` ones) and do nothing else
2. Apply filters yourself, and don't return `forFilterOnly` fields.

1 is the most common solution. While 2 can result in better performance for some connectors, many won't see a significant benefit, and the complexity of their code will increase.

As an aside, I can see how the docs are confusing here, I'll update them to clarify this point.

Thanks